# C++ DLL derived class segregation

Tags: c++, windows, dll, architecture, polymorphism

I build a dll let's call it device.dll containing a C++ base class "device" which has 4-5 different derived classes inheriting from it all with their own implementation and own dependencies (other DLLs). As things stand my device.dll depends on every dll dependency of all devices. This means I have 50 DLLs depending on device.dll but some users only require 10 DLLs for using device type 1. I'd like to make it more modular so that someone wanting only to use device type 1 does not require the DLL dependencies of device type 2,3,4... Is it possible to achieve this? Would the best solution be to build a DLL for each device type and have my device.dll load the derived device dll at run time?

Comment: You asked yourself: load DLL at runtime with `LoadLibraryW` and `GetProcAddress`

Comment: Hi Osyotr thanks for your response. Would this be the best solution? Or am I missing something better?

Comment: This is how plugin system is implemented in virtually all modern software.